# Display vertical lines with arows in Ext Tree panel

Tags: extjs

How to implement vertical line and arrows altogether in Ext Tree?

I have created a fiddle by using both properties of `useArrows` and `lines`, but not getting applied at the same time.

```
     Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title: 'Simple Tree',
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        store: store,
        rootVisible: true,
        lines:true,
        useArrows: true,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32r3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useArows` and `lines` in tree is mutually exclusive properties

[image]

But you can use next hack - set `useArrow` and manually set `linesCls`, and override some css classes.

Look at my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32r8)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the source code for the `Ext.tree.Panel` ExtJs will not give the tree panel the lines CSS if the `@cfg useArrows` is true.

```
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this,
        cls = [me.treeCls],
        store, autoTree, view;

    if (me.useArrows) {
        cls.push(me.arrowCls);
        me.lines = false;
    }

    if (me.lines) {
        cls.push(me.linesCls);
    } else if (!me.useArrows) {
        cls.push(me.noLinesCls);
    }
....}
```

You have two options here in my opinion:

1. You override the `initComponent` method for this `Ext.tree.Panel`
2. You can override the css classes to implement the arrow-images

I made a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32r7) for the second case. This is what you wanted?